# sql query to validate the form which has from and to date and it should allow only for current date not the next day

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date

I have a form where have to enter from and to date in `date picker` , but while saving the data the from date and to date should be for the current date. And if i enter to date as tomorrows date it should not allow to save the date.Kindly let me know as how to do this in `mysql` . May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

Comment: `from_date` and `to_date` have to be current date..?? anyway, you can just do an input-checking (compare with the system's date) on the application level (not on DB level).. is that what you want?

Comment: yes thats right how to do that can you please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure on what you are trying to achieve...

In general, if you have to validate a form you should it in your java code before inserting stuffs into the DB.

You can check ad a DB level using a trigger (BEFORE INSERT) or a constraint (you can use the constraint anyway to ensure the data integrity) but I believe that a check in Java is easier to maintain.

Comment: alright will do it in java can u tell as how to do the same

Comment: dont have idea how to do that how to do that

Comment: Ok... Can you post the code that you use to insert in the db so I can edit on that?

Comment: select * from tablename where fromtime<=now() and totime>=now();

Comment: Sorry, I mean the Java code that you use\ to insert your data in the database

Comment: How do you get your data in the database then? And BTW this question is tagged with "Java", if it's not about java you should remove that tag

Answer (score 0):

This way you can do it..

> 1. It takes date from screen.. (You have to parse date from string)
> 2. It takes today's date of midnight
> 3. It takes tomorrow's date of midnight
> 4. Check that screen's date should be between today's midnight and tomorrow's midnight

```
Date date_from_screen = new Date();

Date today = new Date();
today.setHours(0);
today.setMinutes(0);
today.setSeconds(0);

Date tomorrow = new Date(today.getTime() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
tomorrow.setHours(0);
tomorrow.setMinutes(0);
tomorrow.setSeconds(0);


if((date_from_screen.getTime() >= today.getTime()) &&  (date_from_screen.getTime() <= tomorrow.getTime()))
{
    System.out.println("valid date");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("invalide date");
}
```

Comment: but where did you get the date from screen

Comment: You have html form right ? When you submit the form you will get that date value in string. that value you have to parse in java.util.Date

Answer (score 0):

another reference for java 8 users:

if you are referring to:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html

then you just need to play with:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html

```
final DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(); //assuming this is your DatePicker on the form
LocalDate date = datePicker.getValue();

//comparing with current date (LocalDate.now())
if(date.compareTo(LocalDate.now())!=0)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input date!");
}
else{
    //save to DB..
}
```

note: I haven't tried to run this though..